# Jmeter - how get unique urls from webpage

Tags: jmeter, http-request

I am new in jmeter and I cannot find answer to my question. I want to call all internal links on website. Tutorial helped me in collecting all links. However some of them are repeated. And I want to call only unique links - so 1 link 1 call.

I am calling my webpage and by regular expression extractor I am collecting all links. And as a result I have variables which store links. But unfortunately some of them are repeated and as a result I am calling more than once some links.

Anybody has idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your links come from Regular Expression Extractor you should be having something like:

```
LINK=http://foo.bar
LINK_1=http://foo.bar
LINK_2=http://example.com
LINK_3=http://example.com
LINK_matchNr=3
```

JMeter doesn't provide an appropriate test element to eliminate duplicates in such situations, but you still can work it around via some scripting.

In order to do so

1. Add a [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) **after** your Regular Expression Extractor
2. Put the following code into the PostProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   int matches = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("LINK_matchNr"));
   Set links = new HashSet();

   for (int i = 1; i <= matches; i++) {

     links.add(vars.get("LINK_" + i));
     vars.remove("LINK_" + i);
   }

   int counter = 1;
   for (String link : links) {
     vars.put("LINK_" + counter, link);
     counter++;
   }
   ```

So your test plan would look as follows:

[image: Beanshell PostProcessor]

Beanshell code in the PostProcessor

- iterates through all JMeter Variables starting with `LINK_`
- stores their values into Java [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) which cannot contain duplicate values as it's hash-based. So all duplicate variable values will be silently ignored
- removes variables as they're being iterated
- builds new variables from HashSet

So finally you'll have JMeter Variables in their initial form but without duplicates.

**Important:** Beanshell Code above assumes that you use `LINK` as a "Reference Name" in your Regular Expression Extractor, make sure that you either change it to `LINK` there or update Beanshell code to match your Reference Name

For advanced information on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter refer to [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.